# How do I find newly installed applications in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I have installed Google Chromium for Ubuntu, but I cannot find it.  It's not in the launcher or in installed applications.

Comment: How did you install it?  What is the output of `whereis chromium-browser`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/list.txt
```

The above command will create a text file in your Desktop containing all the installed packages. You can now open it using a text editor to view the contents.

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer, "what's next?"

Comment: @edwin: i've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found both chromium browser and google chrome, managed to find the open file, and opened google chrome, and then locked to launcher.  Success!

Answer (score 0):

You installed either `chromium-browser` or `google-chrome` but not `Google Chromium`.

To check what you did most recently, if you installed via the Software Center or by using `sudo apt-get`, check `/var/log/apt/history.log.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found both chromium browser and google chrome, managed to find the open file, and opened google chrome, and then locked to launcher. Success!